# Rails 3 renaming routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, rename

I am just getting started with Rails 3 and I do not quite understand how to go about renaming routes.

**What I want:**

To rename the path to the `users#show` controller/action pair.  So instead of the URL being `www.example.com/users/show/1` it would just be `www.example.com/1/home`

In the future, I'd also like to be able to add additional paths onto the end such as:

`www.example.com/1/home/profile/`

**How my user resources are set up:**

```
resources :users, :except => [:destroy] do
  resources :favorites, :only => [:show, :update]
  resources :profiles, :only => [:show, :update]
end
```

**What I tried:**

```
match :home, :to => 'users#show'
```

**What happened:**

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show

  Couldn't find User without an ID
```

**What's in the development.log file:**

```
Started GET "/home" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-03-10 13:36:15 -0500
  Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  [1m[35mUser Load (1.6ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" = 101) LIMIT 1
Completed   in 192ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User without an ID):
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:19:in `show'
```

**What's in the user controller:**

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.haml
  end
end
```

So, apparently it is storing the user id, as shown in the development log as `101` but for whatever reason I am still getting this error?

Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should provide a segment key in your match:

```
match ':id/home' => 'users#show'
```

But with this renaming you will get not RESTful routes.

Another thing is with user profiles. If one user can have only one profile it's better to declare singular resource routes:

```
resources :users do
  resource :profile
end
```

Comment: That gives a routing error: `No route matches {:controller=>"users", :action=>"show"}`

Comment: It looks like it is looking for a `show` action in the `new` action of the **User** controller... `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:controller=>"users", :action=>"show"}):
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:33:in 'new'`

Comment: You have something wrong with your `root :to =>`. At first place it at the bottom of routes. If it won't help please show your routes.rb.

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain why it's making that SQL request, but it's not using 101 to look up the user. If it were, you would get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with ID=101
```

Since it says `Coundln't find User without and ID`, then it's probably calling `User.find(nil)`

Anyway, we're doing something similar in our application, except with names instead of IDs. They are matched at the bottom of the routes file, like so:

```
match '/:current_region' => 'offers#show', :as => 'region_home'
```

and then in your controller, you can load the model from the parameter `params[:current_region]`:

```
def load_region
    @current_region = Region.find_by_slug(params[:current_region] || cookies[:current_region])
end
```

We use it as a filter before a lot of actions, so we define it like so rather than explicitly call it in the `show` action:

```
class OffersController < ActionController::Base
    before_filter :load_region

    def show
        # do stuff with @current_region here
    end
end
```

You'll just have to change `:current_region` to `:id`

Comment: I apologize, but being as new to Rails as I am, looking at your code is just confusing me even more.  If you could show me using my code, it would be easier for me to understand.